# Excel macro to create date coloms

Tags: excel-formula

I just want to create list of months automatically between start and end dates in which if the starting date or the end date have only dates then it comes as date from to in excel.

Answer (score 0):

If `A1` contains the starting date, and `A2` is the enddate, then

```
=TEXT(IF(EDATE($A$1,ROW() - 5) <= $A$2, EDATE($A$1,ROW() - 5), ""), "mmmyy")
```

does what you ask for. Just apply it for sufficiently many cells.